# Setting up Tor for use with stem

Tags: stem

I frequently use either Tor Browser or Tails. Now I would like to do something entirely different and want to use [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/). The tutorials on that site all presuppose that Tor is installed separately from the Tor Browser but I'm having trouble finding the documentation about the best way to install and configure Tor as a stand-alone. Nor, to my surprise, did I find any question addressing the point here (perhaps I searched for the wrong thing). But, hence the questions ...

1. What should I be reading?
2. If I use the synaptic package manager to install Tor in, say, Linux
   Mint, will I get the most recent stable version of Tor?
3. When I installed Tor (briefly) some years ago through the synaptic
   manager, it immediately started Tor and set it running at log-in
   time, which I did not want. Is that still the case, and how can I
   avoid it?

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please note that Stem is perfectly usable with the Tor Browser: `python -c 'from stem.control import Controller; c = Controller.from_port("127.0.0.1", 9151); c.authenticate(); print c.get_version()'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- What should I be reading?

It depends on your platform but since your on a deb based distro it should be easy...

https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

- If I use the synaptic package manager to install Tor in, say, Linux Mint, will I get the most recent stable version of Tor?

Not by default, but it will be if you get it from deb.torproject.org. See the second step of the above link.

- When I installed Tor (briefly) some years ago through the synaptic manager, it immediately started Tor and set it running at log-in time, which I did not want. Is that still the case, and how can I avoid it?

IIRC turning it off is as simple as `sudo /etc/init.d/tor stop`.